# save a file on a local machine from a flex web app

Tags: apache-flex

is there a way to save, not save as, from an online flex app onto someone's local machine? Basically, if a user opens a file local to their machine in an online flex app, is there a way to allow them to save it locally without going through dialog boxes and picking file names?

Note: I've read that this is possible on Air, but seems unlikely in Flex - my hope is that  some workaround may exist...

thx!

f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For security reasons, the online application does not have access to the user's harddrive.  This is why the "save as" functionality has been added.  It allows the user to choose to save a file.

Comment: Right. And I assume no workarounds that you know of? Someone mentioned Local Shared Objects as a potential path, but it's unclear to me whether that could work. thank you!

Comment: Local Shared Objects are like binary browser cookies.

Comment: No.  There are no workarounds.  The ONLY way to write to the users hard drive, is with through help of the user.  This is by design.  If you were to find a way around this, that would be a security hole, and it would need to be closed.

Comment: The reason this is possible on AIR is that AIR is not operated inside of the browser.  AIR operates like any windows application.  It runs on the users computer, and under their permissions, etc.